# How to modify command line arguments inside bash script using set

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm executing a shell script and passing few command line arguments to it.

I want to modify the arguments inside the script using `set`. Not all at once depending upon some conditions.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please share some more details about the problem?

Comment: ```./check_test_results.sh $publish_pcom_test  $publish_svs_test``` This is how I'm executing the script. The two arguments are having some default values(True/False). I want to do some operations and want to decide whether I have to modify these argument values or not. If I have to update these values then how can I do that?

Comment: You can access parameter using `$1` and `$2` Check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: @DigvijayS it's not about accessing it, I want to update $1 $2 with some new values using ```set```

Comment: You want to update value of `$publish_pcom_test $publish_svs_test` right ? try `export  $publish_pcom_test="Blah blah "`

Comment: Yes before exporting it, I need to update it to the new values, I have the current values of ```$publish_pcom_test $publish_svs_test``` inside $1 and $2, can I use ```$publish_pcom_test $publish_svs_test``` directly inside script? Like you said ```$publish_pcom_test="Blah blah "``` or I have to do like ```$1="Blah blah"```

Answer (score 1):

Copy unmodified arguments at their respective location within `set --`

Say you want to modify value of argument 2:

```sh
set -- "${@::2}" 'new arg2 value' "${@:3}"
```

Explanation:

- `"${@::2}"`: Expands 2 arguments from index 0 (arguments 0 and 1)
- `new arg2 value`: Becomes the value for argument 2.
- `"${@:3}"`: Expands all argument values starting at index 3.

Opinion:

> Anyway, having mutable arguments is considered code-smell in modern programming. So I'd recommend you reconsider your approach to the problem you are trying to solve.